# How to retrieve the preceding-sibling of (ancestor::w:p) of the current node using xslt2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, linq-to-xml

This is my xml File.

```
<w:document>
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                  <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
               <w:t>Para1</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>

       <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
           <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Para2</w:t>
        </w:r>
        </w:p>

        <w:p>   <!-- Current Node -->
          <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading3"/>   
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r>
              <w:t>Para3</w:t>
          </w:r>
         </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

So,

> 1. Now I want to get the ancestor `<w:p>` of the current node.
> 2. then I need to get the preceding-sibling of this `<w:p>`[1]
> 3. finally need to retrieve the `<w:pPr>-<w:pStyle>`->@w:val of the `<w:p>`[1].

I tried this one... But failed...

```
preceding-sibling::(ancestor::w:p)[1]/w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val
```

Comment: Test my answer. It should be what you are searching for. I think you just need to use axis in the correct way.

Comment: There was a typo (missing 'l') in the XPath. Check my answer now.

Comment: empo:What happen if current node is last <w:p> node...

Comment: empo:thanks empo, but i already modified before testing...

Comment: Please make your question clear. Which is the current node?

Comment: empo:yes.What needs to change now?

Comment: empo:Please see my modified question now

Comment: empo:One more correction in your Answer is "sibling" not sibiling.

Comment: Yes sorry, this morning I have a problem with the keybord which is not typing correctly the 'l'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want:

```
ancestor::w:p[1]/preceding-sibling::w:p[1]/w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val
```

if your current node is `<w:pStyle w:val="Heading3"/>`.

If current node is `w:p` you don't want the ancestor anymore, but the direct preceding sibling:

```
preceding-sibling::w:p[1]/w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val
```

Hope it helps.